# Append duplicate records with count (mysql)

Tags: mysql

We need to update a set of titles that have some duplicate entries. Because of the size of the database I would prefer to use direct mysql method, but I am open to any solutions out there.

If we have records (url_title):

```
a-stoney
a-stoney
ab-dille
ab-dille
ab-dille
ac-gifta
ae-jones
ae-jones
```

I want to be able to run against the table and end up with ONLY the duplicate url_titles updated as follows:

```
a-stoney
a-stoney-1
ab-dille
ab-dille-1
ab-dille-2
ac-gifta
ae-jones
ae-jones-1
```

Or some similar output, where non-duplicate url-titles are not edited, and any duplicates are applied a similar convention

Table syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE `exp_channel_titles` (
  `entry_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `site_id` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `channel_id` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `author_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `forum_topic_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url_title` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `versioning_enabled` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
  `view_count_one` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `view_count_two` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `view_count_three` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `view_count_four` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `allow_comments` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'y',
  `sticky` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
  `entry_date` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `year` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `month` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `day` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `expiration_date` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment_expiration_date` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `edit_date` bigint(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `recent_comment_date` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment_total` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entry_id`),
  KEY `channel_id` (`channel_id`),
  KEY `author_id` (`author_id`),
  KEY `url_title` (`url_title`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `entry_date` (`entry_date`),
  KEY `expiration_date` (`expiration_date`),
  KEY `site_id` (`site_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=181332 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    enter code here
```

Comment: Please show the actual table structure using `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable\G`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the sake of this question, I will call the source table `aaronlax`

## PROPOSED SOLUTION

```
SET @ndx = 0;
SET @cur_hash = '';
SELECT entry_id,CONCAT(url_title,IF(ndx>0,CONCAT('-',ndx),'')) url_title
FROM (SELECT
   @new_hash := MD5(url_title),
   (@ndx := IF(@new_hash=@cur_hash,@ndx+1,0)) ndx,
   @cur_hash := MD5(url_title),
   url_title,entry_id
FROM (SELECT url_title,entry_id FROM aaronlax ORDER BY url_title) AA) A;
```

## SAMPLE DATA

```
use test
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS aaronlax;
CREATE TABLE aaronlax
(
    entry_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    url_title varchar(75) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (entry_id),
    KEY (url_title)    
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
INSERt INTO aaronlax (url_title) VALUES
('a-stoney'),('a-stoney'),
('ab-dille'),('ab-dille'),
('ab-dille'),('ac-gifta'),
('ae-jones'),('ae-jones');
```

## SAMPLE DATA LOADED

```
mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS aaronlax;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE aaronlax
    -> (
    ->     entry_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->     url_title varchar(75) NOT NULL,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (entry_id),
    ->     KEY (url_title)
    -> ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> INSERt INTO aaronlax (url_title) VALUES
    -> ('a-stoney'),('a-stoney'),
    -> ('ab-dille'),('ab-dille'),
    -> ('ab-dille'),('ac-gifta'),
    -> ('ae-jones'),('ae-jones');
Query OK, 8 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 8  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from aaronlax;
+----------+-----------+
| entry_id | url_title |
+----------+-----------+
|        1 | a-stoney  |
|        2 | a-stoney  |
|        3 | ab-dille  |
|        4 | ab-dille  |
|        5 | ab-dille  |
|        6 | ac-gifta  |
|        7 | ae-jones  |
|        8 | ae-jones  |
+----------+-----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

mysql>

## PROPOSED SOLUTION EXECUTED

```
mysql> SET @ndx = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @cur_hash = '';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT entry_id,CONCAT(url_title,IF(ndx>0,CONCAT('-',ndx),'')) url_title
    -> FROM (SELECT
    ->    @new_hash := MD5(url_title),
    ->    (@ndx := IF(@new_hash=@cur_hash,@ndx+1,0)) ndx,
    ->    @cur_hash := MD5(url_title),
    ->    url_title,entry_id
    -> FROM (SELECT url_title,entry_id FROM aaronlax ORDER BY url_title) AA) A;
+----------+------------+
| entry_id | url_title  |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | a-stoney   |
|        2 | a-stoney-1 |
|        3 | ab-dille   |
|        4 | ab-dille-1 |
|        5 | ab-dille-2 |
|        6 | ac-gifta   |
|        7 | ae-jones   |
|        8 | ae-jones-1 |
+----------+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

#### CAVEAT

In case you are wondering why the proposed solution works, let's take a look at the subqueries

#### INNERMOST SUBQUERY

```
mysql> SELECT url_title,entry_id FROM aaronlax ORDER BY url_title;
+-----------+----------+
| url_title | entry_id |
+-----------+----------+
| a-stoney  |        1 |
| a-stoney  |        2 |
| ab-dille  |        3 |
| ab-dille  |        4 |
| ab-dille  |        5 |
| ac-gifta  |        6 |
| ae-jones  |        7 |
| ae-jones  |        8 |
+-----------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

#### NEXT LEVEL SUBQUERY

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->    @new_hash := MD5(url_title),
    ->    (@ndx := IF(@new_hash=@cur_hash,@ndx+1,0)) ndx,
    ->    @cur_hash := MD5(url_title),
    ->    url_title,entry_id
    -> FROM (SELECT url_title,entry_id FROM aaronlax ORDER BY url_title) AA;
+----------------------------------+------+----------------------------------+-----------+----------+
| @new_hash := MD5(url_title)      | ndx  | @cur_hash := MD5(url_title)      | url_title | entry_id |
+----------------------------------+------+----------------------------------+-----------+----------+
| 911adc6db360f218da5069b20cfb1917 |    0 | 911adc6db360f218da5069b20cfb1917 | a-stoney  |        1 |
| 911adc6db360f218da5069b20cfb1917 |    1 | 911adc6db360f218da5069b20cfb1917 | a-stoney  |        2 |
| b468c0dd0ef78fde7cf5ae14765f9a5a |    0 | b468c0dd0ef78fde7cf5ae14765f9a5a | ab-dille  |        3 |
| b468c0dd0ef78fde7cf5ae14765f9a5a |    1 | b468c0dd0ef78fde7cf5ae14765f9a5a | ab-dille  |        4 |
| b468c0dd0ef78fde7cf5ae14765f9a5a |    2 | b468c0dd0ef78fde7cf5ae14765f9a5a | ab-dille  |        5 |
| 3fff0367af8bf5d3b3b0089b8f187c04 |    0 | 3fff0367af8bf5d3b3b0089b8f187c04 | ac-gifta  |        6 |
| 1909ba0f7a57ca081c82d2f7ba54c9e5 |    0 | 1909ba0f7a57ca081c82d2f7ba54c9e5 | ae-jones  |        7 |
| 1909ba0f7a57ca081c82d2f7ba54c9e5 |    1 | 1909ba0f7a57ca081c82d2f7ba54c9e5 | ae-jones  |        8 |
+----------------------------------+------+----------------------------------+-----------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

From this level, I only need three columns: `entry_id`, `url_title`, `ndx` in the outer most level

Then, I append to the `url_title` a hyphen and `ndx` if `ndx` is nonzero

Comment: As a SELECT this works PERFECTLY, can you recommend an adjustment to run this as an UPDATE so the existing table is set to reflect the corrected +ndx output?

Comment: Same question here, did anybody figure this out as an update already @AaronLax

Answer (score 0):

Two people asked in comments to the other answer, how to turn this select into an update statement.

It's pretty straightforward, with an update on the original table joined with the table created by the select statement:

```
SET @ndx = 0;
SET @cur_hash = '';

UPDATE aaronlax
JOIN (

SELECT entry_id,CONCAT(url_title,IF(ndx>0,CONCAT('-',ndx),'')) url_title
FROM (SELECT
   @new_hash := MD5(url_title),
   (@ndx := IF(@new_hash=@cur_hash,@ndx+1,0)) ndx,
   @cur_hash := MD5(url_title),
   url_title,entry_id
FROM (SELECT url_title,entry_id FROM aaronlax ORDER BY url_title) AA) A

) U

ON aaronlax.entry_id = U.entry_id
SET aaronlax.url_title = U.url_title
```